# Wordpress: Removing meta tag for specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I would like to remove the following meta tag form a specific page on a WordPress website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

This is to disable default zoom on mobile devices, I have found out the following function can do this:

```
<?php remove_meta_box( $id, $page, $context ); ?>
```

Not quite sure how to apply it, the name of the page on which the meta tag has to be removed is called 'plans'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `$("meta[name=viewport]").remove()` ?

Comment: It all depends on your template that you are using. Is there a `custom.php` included in your template??

Comment: @guest271314: I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: @CarlK: I'm using the famous Avada template, not sure custom.php is a part of it, I guess this function can be added in the child theme's functions.php file, would like to know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Find the code `add_filter('wp_head', 'viewport_meta');` in your functions.php file then replace it with below code.

```
global $post;
if($post->ID == [Your page id in which page you dont need viewport meta]) {
    add_filter('wp_head', 'viewport_meta');
}
```

This may help you.